# Html Tag in code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to create nested tags in asp.net c# code behind.
it's:

```
 <fieldset>
                <legend>دسترسی ها</legend>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>'<%# Eval("Group") %>'</legend>
                    <div style="width: 95%; margin: auto; padding: 0px 5% 0px 0px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
                        <div class="tblHeader">
                            <div class="TblTitle">عنوان</div>
                            <div class="TblChk">دارد</div>
                            <div class="TblChk">اصلا ندارد</div>
                            <div class="TblTitle">عنوان</div>
                            <div class="TblChk">دارد</div>
                            <div class="TblChk">اصلا ندارد</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="TblTitle">
                                <span>'<%# Eval("Item") %>'</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="TblChk">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="10-1" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="TblChk">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="10-1" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="TblTitle">
                                <span>'<%# Eval("Item") %>'</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="TblChk">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="11" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="TblChk">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="11" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
```

in fact I have many groups that contains some child in here is `'<%# Eval("Item") %>'`.
How can I do it?
If i used `DataList` , `'<%# Eval("Group") %>'`was duplicate and it's not my purpose .
I want to display them such as below picture:
[image]

Comment: What is your **exact** problem? Right now it is hard to deduce - what are you asking...

Comment: @AndyKorneyev , sorry ,I explained  it,do you have any solution? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Panel` instead which is rendered as a div but is a pure server control. Nesting them is easy, you just need to create the panels and add them to the outer-panel's `Controls`-property.

So you could use a `PlaceHolder`-control (which is a container that is not rendered itself):

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PanelContainer" runat="server">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In codebehind add a method like this:

```
private void DataBindPanelContainer()
{
    Panel main = new Panel();
    main.CssClass = "ItemData";

    Panel tblTitle = new Panel();
    tblTitle.CssClass = "TblTitle";
    Label lblTitle = new Label();
    lblTitle.ID = "LblTitle";
    lblTitle.Text = someField;  // i don't know your datasource
    tblTitle.Controls.Add(lblTitle);
    main.Controls.Add(tblTitle);

    Panel tblChk = new Panel();
    tblChk.CssClass = "TblChk";
    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    chk.ID = "Chk1";
    chk.Text = "text for checkbox";
    tblChk.Controls.Add(chk);
    main.Controls.Add(tblChk);

    // ....
    this.PanelContainer.Controls.Add(main);
}
```

and call it from `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBindPanelContainer();
}
```